# Xtext grammar in two files

Tags: code-generation, xtext

I want to put my terminals into a separate file, because I'll use an external lexer in the production version.  I tried following the answer to [using custom terminals definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660653/xtext-use-custom-terminals-definitions).  So I have a `mypackage/Tokens.xtext` file and a `mypackage/MyDsl.xtext` file containing

```
grammar mypackage.MyDsl with mypackage.Tokens
```

The generation works fine, but it creates a `MyDslStandaloneSetupGenerated` in `src-gen` which doesn't compile, because it calls the non-existent `mypackage.TokensStandaloneSetup.doSetup()`.  It also generates `src-gen/mypackage/services/MyDslGrammarAccess` which refers to an also non-existent `TokensGrammarAccess` class.  So my question is basically: when I have another grammar file, what else should I do to make it usable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to also run a generator for the token grammar.

Comment: That means I have to write some additional file(s), including a generator?  What other files are to be written?

Answer (score 0):

in Xtext you usually put the tokens (terminals) and the parser rules into the same .xtext file. Is there a specific reason why you want to split this?

Comment: I would like to do the same thing. My reason is that I generate the "base-grammar" and would like to put the generated token in a seperate file.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Reason:

`Easier to Read and work with the Grammar for everybody (especially other users)`

Seems like Xtext still does not support the use of more than one .xtext file