# How to create custom terminal grammar for xtext?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, grammar, xtext

My grammar file is already too large and is causing the error:
The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit.

So, I want to split my grammar into 2 xtext files, and create a separate custom terminal.xtext to lower down the size of my grammar file.

I have an xtext project in org.xtext.rpcIDL, where my RpcIDL.xtext is in its src directory.
I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660653/xtext-use-custom-terminals-definitions) that its possible to have 2  grammar files in one project. But I cannot add another grammar file in my current project. When I right-click, then go to New, there is no option there to add a new xtext file.

How can I add a custom xtext file in my project?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already found out the solution by yourself but in case you didn't:
To create a new Xtext-File in your project right click in your `org.xtext.rpcIDL`which should be in your text-project under src (The one with the package symbol in front of it), then go to New->File and then you just have to give it a name and add the extension `.xtext`. That will add the xtext-nature to your project. After that you have to add the line `grammar ...` (just copy this line of your other file and change the last element to the name of your new File). Then add `with` and enter the name of your other xtext-file (this is the one which stands after the `generate` in your other file. Then you should be able to use the elements of all the features which you have declared in your original File.
I hope I could help you.
Greets Krzmbrzl